# Como passar id da empresa para a tabela dos funcionários?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela empresa e outra funcionário.

**Tabela empresa**:

```
id_emp | tipo | documento | fantasia | email | celular | senha | data_cadastro | ativo
```

Exemplo:

```
 1 | pessoa juridica | 05.142.333/0001-21 | petstop caes e gatos | petshop@gmail.com | (21) 8651-0801 | MD5 | 22/11/2015 | 09:49:00 | 1
```

**Tabela funcionário**:

```
id_func | sexo | nome | sobrenome | funcao | celular | email | senha | ativo | data_cadastro | id_emp
```

Exemplo:

```
1 | M | Paulo | Santos | veterinario | (21)8651-0001 | paulor@gmail.com | MD5 | 1 | 22/11/2015 | 09:49:00 | 1 | ???
```

Antes da minha pergunta, vou informar o procedimento que eu faço para chegar até aqui: No meu site, a empresa *(petstop caes e gatos)* faz o cadastro dela. Após o cadastro, o sistema envia um link para o e-mail cadastrado *(petshop@gmail.com)* com a senha MD5. E, vai um link para a ativação do mesmo. Quando faz a ativação, logo abaixo ele faz o login.

Fiz usando este exemplo [aqui](http://www.fabiobmed.com.br/sistema-de-cadastro-de-usuarios-e-login-com-sessions/).

Foi criado um formulário de cadastro de funcionário, ou seja, após fazer o login, ele vai cadastrar o funcionário, e após salvar, na tabela funcionário, associar este à empresa.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Mas, qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Aproveitando que ja leu o [tour], leia também o [ask]. :)

Comment: Estou querendo pegar a id da empresa e jogar no campo id_emp do cadastro do funcionário.

Comment: no momento do cadastro da empresa você também cadastra um funcionário?

Comment: Certo, mas você está usando o que? No PHP, PDO? No banco de dados, MySQL, etc.. Sem tantos detalhes fica difícil responder.

Comment: Estou usando Mysql + PHP

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar um campo no formulário com `type="hidden"` e com o `ID` da empresa sendo o `value` desse campo.

Ao enviar o formulário, você captura o valor desse campo e salva na coluna `id_emp` na tabela `funcionário`. Por exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_emp" value="1">
```

Comment: para pegar o valor desse campo usa: $id_emp = POST['id_emp']. Depois é só colocar no INSERT que grava no banco.

Comment: Eu não tenho que pegar a url da empresa que acessou através do link de ativação?

Answer (score 0):

Isso na verdade seria um relacionamento com chave primaria `id_emp` na tabela `empresa` e chave estrangeira `id_emp` na tabela `funcionario`. NO próprio phpmyadmin vc consegue criar os índices e depois criar o relacionamento entre essas duas tabelas.

Segue link para referência: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HryLal--ZI)

Comment: Ok Igor! Talvez eu tenha interpretado errado a minha pergunta no fórum.
No meu site, pode ser cadastrado várias empresas e cada empresa com os seus funcionários. Então, após o administrador da empresa fazer o cadastro, vai o link para ele. Neste link está indo o ID da empresa, porém, no formulário de cadastro do funcionário, não aparece a id da empresa para vincular este funcionário. Entendeu?